# how to add connection strings to the Web project programatically/dynamically at run time

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamic, connection-string, ria

How do i work on 2 or more different data sources coming from different servers and expose APIs on the Web project where i can add more connections strings programmatically to the web project from the client side?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Connection Strings? Change the connection object. Even if you use something automagic, like LINQ to SQL or EF, you have the ability to change the connection string at runtime. You have to know what connection string you are changing it to, but that can even be sent into the service from your silverlight application (although "never trust user input" comes to mind when working with a "public API").

The same holds true for SOA type implementations where the "connection string" means the service URI.

If you want something more concrete, be more specific on what you are contacting and how.